# ProFTPd : SFTP "get" command is denied (when "put" works ok)

Tags: redhat, sftp, proftpd

I have this issue on RHEL 8.6 with proftpd 1.3.8a

I have a proftpd server setup, with a user called IFTPTEST. In its home, this user has 2 directories, in/ and out/.
My goal is : I put files in the out/ directory, and the user connects to the server (with user/password) to fetch the file.

When the user connects, it can go inside the out/ directory, list the content of the directory and put files in the directory.
However, when it tries to get the file, I have a *Permission denied* error :

```
sftp> ls -al
drwxrwxr-x    3 IFTPTEST 1000         4096 Nov  9 10:02 .
drwxrwxr-x    3 IFTPTEST 1000         4096 Nov  9 10:02 ..
drwxrwxr-x    2 IFTPTEST 1000         4096 Nov  9 10:08 in
drwxrwxrwx    2 IFTPTEST 1000         4096 Nov  9 10:05 out
sftp> cd out
sftp> ls -al
drwxrwxrwx    2 IFTPTEST 1000         4096 Nov  9 10:05 .
drwxrwxr-x    3 IFTPTEST 1000         4096 Nov  9 10:02 ..
-rwxrwxrwx    1 IFTPTEST 1000           13 Nov  9 10:05 test
sftp> get test test.txt
Fetching /out/test to test.txt
remote open("/out/test"): Permission denied
```

Even with the out/ directory and the test file with 777 rights, I get the *Permission denied*.

In the sftp.log, I can see :

```
OPEN command for '/out/test' blocked by 'RETR' handler
```

And in /var/log/messages :

```
RETR /appli_var/XFRF/xfrf_files/ftpusers/IFTPTEST/out/test denied by <Limit> configuration
```

Which I don't understand, because I have the RETR setup for the out/ directory in my proftpd.conf (see below).

Is this a known problem ? Do I have a problem in my config ?

---

Content of the proftpd.conf (I didn't put the whole file) :

```
# Proftpd server configuration

[...]

LoadModule mod_vroot.c
<Global>
   VRootEngine              on
   VRootLog                 /appli_var/XFRF/proftpd/vroot.log
   VRootOptions             allowSymlinks
   DefaultRoot ~
</Global>

[...]

# Directory limits
<Global>
   <Directory />
      <Limit ALL>
         DenyAll
      </Limit>
      <Limit CDUP CWD LIST MDTM MLSD MLST NLST PWD STAT XCUP XPWD OPENDIR READDIR REALPATH LSTAT FSTAT SETSTAT STOR SITE_CHMOD>
         AllowAll
      </Limit>
   </Directory>
   <Directory /in>
      <Limit ALL>
         DenyAll
      </Limit>
      <Limit CDUP CWD LIST MDTM MLSD MLST NLST PWD STAT XCUP XPWD RETR SIZE APPE DELE RNFR RNTO STOR STOU SITE_CHMOD SETSTAT FSETSTAT LSTAT FSTAT READ>
         AllowAll
      </Limit>
   </Directory>
   <Directory /out>
      <Limit ALL>
         DenyAll
      </Limit>
      <Limit CDUP CWD LIST MDTM MLSD MLST NLST PWD STAT XCUP XPWD RETR SIZE DELE SITE_CHMOD SETSTAT FSETSTAT LSTAT FSTAT READ>
         AllowAll
      </Limit>
   </Directory>
</Global>

[...]

LoadModule mod_sftp.c
# SFTP virtual server (user/password authentication)
# ----------------------------------------------------
<VirtualHost 10.19.xx.xxx>
    <Limit LOGIN>
      AllowAll
    </Limit>
    ServerName                  "SFTP Server"
    Port                        20022
    AccessGrantMsg              "Welcome to SFTP %u"
    SFTPEngine                  on
    SFTPHostKey                 /appli/XFRF/proftpd/etc/ssh/proftpd_dsa_key
    SFTPHostKey                 /appli/XFRF/proftpd/etc/ssh/proftpd_rsa_key
    SFTPHostKey                 /appli/XFRF/proftpd/etc/ssh/proftpd_ecdsa_key
    SFTPAuthMethods             password
    SFTPCompression             delayed
    SFTPLog                     /appli_var/XFRF/proftpd/sftp.log
    ExtendedLog                 /appli_var/XFRF/proftpd/sftp_extended.log
    TransferLog                 /appli_var/XFRF/proftpd/sftp_transfer.log
    ServerLog                   /appli_var/XFRF/proftpd/sftp_server.log
</VirtualHost>

[...]
```

---

If necessary, more I can see in the /var/log/messages :

```
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'LSTAT /out/test' to mod_tls
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'LSTAT /out/test' to mod_exec
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'LSTAT /out/test' to mod_core
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'LSTAT /out/test' to mod_core
in dir_check(): setting umask to 0022 (was 0022)
dispatching POST_CMD command 'LSTAT /out/test' to mod_exec
dispatching LOG_CMD command 'LSTAT /out/test' to mod_log
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'STAT /out/test' to mod_tls
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'STAT /out/test' to mod_exec
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'STAT /out/test' to mod_core
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'STAT /out/test' to mod_core
in dir_check(): setting umask to 0022 (was 0022)
dispatching POST_CMD command 'STAT /out/test' to mod_exec
dispatching LOG_CMD command 'STAT /out/test' to mod_log
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'RETR /out/test' to mod_tls
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'RETR /out/test' to mod_exec
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'RETR /out/test' to mod_core
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'RETR /out/test' to mod_core
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'RETR /out/test' to mod_vroot
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'RETR /out/test' to mod_vroot
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'RETR /out/test' to mod_auth
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'RETR /out/test' to mod_xfer
in dir_check_full(): path = '/appli_var/XFRF/xfrf_files/ftpusers/IFTPTEST/out/test', fullpath = '/appli_var/XFRF/xfrf_files/ftpusers/IFTPTEST/out/test'
RETR /appli_var/XFRF/xfrf_files/ftpusers/IFTPTEST/out/test denied by <Limit> configuration
dispatching POST_CMD_ERR command 'RETR /out/test' to mod_exec
dispatching POST_CMD_ERR command 'RETR /out/test' to mod_vroot
dispatching POST_CMD_ERR command 'RETR /out/test' to mod_auth
dispatching LOG_CMD_ERR command 'RETR /out/test' to mod_log
dispatching LOG_CMD_ERR command 'RETR /out/test' to mod_xfer
dispatching POST_CMD_ERR command 'OPEN /out/test' to mod_exec
dispatching LOG_CMD_ERR command 'OPEN /out/test' to mod_log
```

Comment: I dont see `RETR` or `GET` inside the allowed commands list?

Comment: I thought that the RETR only needed to be present in the "/out" directory section, but after adding RETR and READ in the "/" section too, the get works alright. Thank you very much, problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RETR` (and `READ` also) command have to be added in the "/" section, not only in the "/ou" section. So with correction it looks like this :

```
# Directory limits
<Global>
   <Directory />
      <Limit ALL>
         DenyAll
      </Limit>
      <Limit CDUP CWD LIST MDTM MLSD MLST NLST PWD STAT XCUP XPWD OPENDIR READDIR REALPATH LSTAT FSTAT SETSTAT STOR SITE_CHMOD READ RETR>
         AllowAll
      </Limit>
   </Directory>
   <Directory /in>
      <Limit ALL>
         DenyAll
      </Limit>
      <Limit CDUP CWD LIST MDTM MLSD MLST NLST PWD STAT XCUP XPWD RETR SIZE APPE DELE RNFR RNTO STOR STOU SITE_CHMOD SETSTAT FSETSTAT LSTAT FSTAT READ>
         AllowAll
      </Limit>
   </Directory>
   <Directory /out>
      <Limit ALL>
         DenyAll
      </Limit>
      <Limit CDUP CWD LIST MDTM MLSD MLST NLST PWD STAT XCUP XPWD RETR SIZE DELE SITE_CHMOD SETSTAT FSETSTAT LSTAT FSTAT READ>
         AllowAll
      </Limit>
   </Directory>
</Global>
```

And with that, the `GET` command works without problem.